# Finding the time difference between two specific SQL rows and populating a new table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, a shortened version is shown below. I need to find the time each ID goes offline. But, if an ID does not come online, it should be ignored, each ID can go offline multiple times, but needs to come online before it can go offline

```
|ID | Description | Time               |
|---|-------------|--------------------|
|1  |Offline      |'2017-09-07 12:53:02|
|---|-------------|--------------------|
|2  |Offline      |'2017-09-07 12:54:00|
|---|-------------|--------------------|
|2  |Online       |'2017-09-07 12:54:01|
|---|-------------|--------------------|
|3  |Offline      |'2017-09-07 12:54:02|
|---|-------------|--------------------|
|1  |Online       |'2017-09-07 12:55:21|
|---|-------------|--------------------|
|2  |Offline      |'2017-09-07 12:57:21|
|---|-------------|--------------------|
|2  |Online       |'2017-09-07 12:58:21|
```

This is the resulting table I need, the order doesn't matter(Time difference can be in seconds)

```
|ID |Time Difference |
|---|----------------|
|1  |141             |
|---|----------------|
|2  |1               |
|---|----------------|
|2  |60              |
```

Comment: The answer worked for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data, the online/offline states are interleaved.  This makes it easy to use `lead()`:

```
select id,
       sum(datediff(second, time, next_t)
from (select t.*,
             lead(description) over (partition by id order by time) as next_d,
             lead(time) over (partition by id order by time) as next_t
      from t
     ) t
where description = 'Offline' and next_d = 'Online';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you can reduce the code size and improve as well.. but the loops are working fine, Replace the (t) with your table name. Hope it works for you.

[image: Select Result]

[image: table]

```
declare @idTable table (i_idx int identity(1,1), id int)
declare @Result table (id int, Time_diff int)
CREATE  table  #Auxtable (i_idx int identity(1,1), id int, Description varchar(50), Time datetime)

insert into @idTable 
select distinct(id) from t

declare @id int
declare @idx int
declare @idx2 int
declare @count int
declare @Offline int
declare @Online int
declare @AuxCount int
declare @auxtableCount int
declare @Description varchar(50)
declare @DescriptionNext varchar(50)
declare @time datetime
declare @timenext datetime

set @idx = 1
set @idx2 = 1
set @count = (select count(*) from @idTable)

while (@idx < @count)
begin
    set @id = (select id from @idTable where i_idx = @idx)
    set @Offline = (select count(*) from t where Description = 'Offline' and id = @idx)
    set @Online = (select count(*) from t where Description = 'Online' and id = @idx)

    if(@Offline > 0 And @Online > 0)
    begin
        insert into #Auxtable select id, Description, Time from t where id = @id order by Time
        set @auxtableCount = (select count(*) from #Auxtable)

        while(@idx2 <= @auxtableCount)
        begin   
            set @Description = (select top 1 Description from #Auxtable where i_idx = @idx2)
            set @DescriptionNext = (select Description from #Auxtable  where i_idx = @idx2 + 1)
            set @time = (select time from #Auxtable where i_idx = @idx2)
            set @timenext = (select time from #Auxtable where i_idx = @idx2 + 1)

            if(@Description = 'Offline' and @DescriptionNext = 'Online')
            begin
                insert into @Result (id, Time_diff) values (@id, datediff(second, @time, @timenext))
                set @idx2 = @idx2 + 1
            end

            set @idx2 = @idx2 + 1
        end

    end
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Auxtable
    SET @idx2 = 1

    set @idx = @idx + 1
end

DROP TABLE #Auxtable

SELECT * FROM @Result
```